# How to set default value to magento short description?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-edit

Currently my store has around 20000+ products. And each product's short description section contains product title at this moment.

I want to replace every product's short description section with following image instead of product title.

[image]

How to bulk replace above image code to magento product Short description section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting a default value for the `short_description` attribute, from the admin panel go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes.  However, you would need to remove all the values set for the existing products.  I would do this with a tool called magmi mass importer.

Perhaps a better approach would be to remove the short description from the product view page and create a static block with your content and add this to the product view page.

For this method you first need to create a static block with your content, next add it to your layout xml, you need to find out the layout handle for your product view page, probably either `PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable` or `PRODUCT_TYPE_simple` or both? Then use the `unset_child action` method to remove the short description or you may need to just comment it out from your theme's `catalog/product/view.phtml` template file if it is not added by layout xml. Then make your recently created static block available to your product page with something like.

```
<block type="cms/block" name="my_identifier"> <action method="setBlockId"><block_id >my_identifier</block_id></action> </block>
```

Finally to add your static block to your product pages use the below code snippet in your phtml template file, next to where the short description was being called.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_identifier') ?>
```

I think the second method is best as your content is not a short description of the product but rather useful information about your store and as such this data should not be held in the 'short_description' attribute which may be used elsewhere in the system, I.e. shopping cart, transactional emails etc.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

**Be sure to make a backup of your SQL DB first.**

Your task could be done by altering Magento's SQL DB directly.

Since Magento uses the EAV (entity-attribute-value) data model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), you first need to find out which attribute ID your Magento uses to set the corresponding values.

Open your Magento DB with phpMyAdmin or something similar. Check your domain/hosting management tool to get access to it.

Open the table `eav_attribute` and search for `short_description` inside the column `attribute_code`. You can use the search of your SQL management tool or simply run the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = "short_description";
```

Note the `attribute_id` from the resulting row.

Now open the table `catalog_product_entity_text` which holds the text inside the product's short description. Do a search for where `attribute_id` is your noted id (number), like (in this case 62):

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` WHERE `attribute_id` = 62;
```

In the column `value` you'll find the product's short description.

Now you can alter all value fields by using this SQL query:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_text`
SET `value` = '<img src="http://domain.com/images/conditions.gif" />'
WHERE `attribute_id` = 62;
```

If you're using different storeViews (maybe as languages) notice that the column `store_id` also plays a role.

**Be sure to make a backup of your SQL DB first.**

Comment: Interesting SQL but it better practice to use Magento to effect the systems data rather than with SQL